# Why following static function doesn't work ?

Tags: c#, .net, action, func

Here is my code :

```
public static class s {

    public static int Dx(this int i, Action<int> act, Func<int, bool> con) {
        if (con(i)) act(i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Later In my code I do :

```
int g = 22;
int false_con = g.Dx(j => j = 11, z => z != 22); // This is 22 which is fine.
int true_con = g.Dx(j => j = 11, z => z == 22);  //This is also 22 which should be 11
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Looks like a simple reference type / value type misunderstanding.

Comment: @AdrianGodong: No, it has nothing to do with reference types and value types. It has to do with the fact that variables are passed by value, regardless of whether the variable is constrained to a reference type or a value type.

Comment: @EricLippert Right, I was confused between (by-)ref and ref-type.

Comment: @AdrianGodong: It is very confusing. I wish the original C# designers had chosen `alias` or `inout` or some other less confusing term than `ref` for a byref variable.

Comment: There is nothing special about `int` here, why not change it to `T` so that you can use this for any given type?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

None of the answers given so far are actual explanations.

A number of the answers given so far state that this happens because int is a value type. Try replacing all the `int`s with `object`s in this program. Does it start working the way the original poster expects? No. Then it has nothing to do with value types vs reference types.

Rather, it has to do with the value of a *variable*, regardless of its type.

Mahdi, your expectation is that formal parameter `j` becomes an *alias* for formal parameter `i`, which is in turn an alias for local variable `g`, and that therefore any change to `j` also causes a change to `g` because they are the same variable. That's not the case. `j`, `i` and `g` are *copies of the same value* but have *different storage locations*, so mutating one does not mutate the other.

The way you say "this formal parameter is an alias for this variable" in C# is by using the `ref` or `out` keywords.  So this program would do what you expect:

```
delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T t);
...
public static int Dx(ref int i, RefAction<int> act, Func<int, bool> con) 
{
    if (con(i)) 
        act(ref i);
    return i;
}
...
int g = 22;
int false_con = Dx(ref g, (ref int j) => { j = 11; }, z => z != 22); 
int true_con = Dx(ref g, (ref int j) => { j = 11; }, z => z == 22);
```

The "ref" keywords mean that `g`, `i`, and `j` are all different names for the same variable.

As D Stanley notes, this is probably bad style. Rather than mutating a variable in a method, instead return the value you want it to be changed to, and let the caller decide what variable to mutate, if any.

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant explanation +1

Answer (score 3):

Your code path doesn't change as a result of calling the `Action`, so the program *always* returns `i`.

It looks like you expect `g` to be changed to 11 after the first call, which is not true since the *value* of g is copied to `j` and then to `i` rather than a *reference* to `g`, meaning the value at `g` is not modified as a result of your action.

One option would be to *return* the value instead of trying to *modify* it:

```
public static int Dx(this int i, Func<int, int> act, Func<int, bool> con) {
    if (con(i)) return act(i);
    return i;
}

int g = 22;
g = g.Dx(j => 11, z => z != 22); /* g is still 22 */ 
g = g.Dx(j => 11, z => z == 22);  /* g is now 11 */
```

Comment: `which is not true since value types are passed by value` **All** objects are passed by values, unless you use the `ref` keyword, in which case the type is passed by reference, regardless of whether it's a value or reference type.  It's the delegate (in this case, `Action<T>` that determines if the parameter is pass by reference or by value.  You could also define a new delegate that passes the parameter by reference (although I'd say the code pattern you've used is much better practice).

Comment: @Servy - yes having a `ref` parameter in a delegate seemed a bit icky to me.

Comment: Again, the solution you have is most likely what he should end up with, but your explanation of why he should use it contains omissions and errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns the integer it is called on, so both cases return `g` which is `22`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to alter the value of `g` through the `Action<int> act`, right?

It won't work as the integer is a primitive type which is passed as value, not as reference, so you're not in fact assigning any value to g.

Comment: Your explanation is not correct. Suppose you changed every int to object in this program. It would still be a legal program. Would it suddenly start working, because now there are only reference types?

Comment: @EricLippert Haha catchy question, as 3 people thought the same thing. Thanks Eric, I stand corrected.